# MySQL: condition takes away notes

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a request, which counts all unremoved notes and unremoved notes with with specific value:

```
SELECT
    catalogs.id AS id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS closed
FROM catalogs
LEFT JOIN links t ON catalogs.id = t.catalog
LEFT JOIN links c ON catalogs.id = c.catalog
WHERE catalogs.removed = 0
    AND ( t.removed = 0 OR t.removed is NULL )
    AND ( c.removed = 0 OR c.removed is NULL )
    AND ( c.is_open = 0 OR c.is_open is NULL )
GROUP BY catalogs.id
ORDER BY catalogs.id;
```

But in responce i can see only notes, where total = 0 or where exists at least one note with c.is_open = 0.

**upd 0:** I'm not very close with sql, but I realized the way i was trying to solve the problem... shame on me :(

**upd 1:** I got another (first in answers) way to make this query with SUM(), the syntax is

```
SUM(case when links.removed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS removed
```

For me this one is easier.

Comment: Please, provide sample data with actual and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the checks on the other columns from the WHERE clause to the ON clauses:-

```
SELECT
    catalogs.id AS id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS closed
FROM catalogs
LEFT JOIN links t ON catalogs.id = t.catalog AND t.removed = 0
LEFT JOIN links c ON catalogs.id = c.catalog AND c.removed = 0 AND ( c.is_open = 0 OR c.is_open is NULL )
WHERE catalogs.removed = 0
GROUP BY catalogs.id
ORDER BY catalogs.id;
```